# Cursor throwing NullPointerException when calling moveToFirst()

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, cursor

I've had a crash report on the Play Store recently that looks like this:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.fillWindow(SQLiteCursor.java:144)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.getCount(SQLiteCursor.java:133)
    at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToPosition(AbstractCursor.java:196)
    at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToFirst(AbstractCursor.java:236)
    at com.myapp.MyActivity(MyActivity.java:283)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

At first I thought it was the cursor being null, but it can't be because I check if it's null before I call `moveToFirst()`

```
mCursor = getCursorData();

if (mCursor != null)
    mCursor.moveToFirst(); // Line 283
```

Can anybody tell me why it is crashing?

Edit:

The code above is pretty much at the start of the method it's inside. This is running inside `onConfigurationChanged()` so I can update the tabs on the activity with the new set from the cursor.

`getCursorData()` is a method inside my `SQLiteOpenHelper`:
The reason I'm using rawQuery is due to the actual query using an INNER JOIN. The query itself is fine as it's worked perfect for a couple years without this exception being thrown.

```
public Cursor getCursorData(long userformid) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();

    return db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM table WHERE _id=?", new String[]{
        String.valueOf(id)
    });
}
```

I've now changed my code to check `getCount()` before calling `moveToFirst()`. I'm just waiting on the user that was having the issue to update to this new version to see if it has worked or not.

Comment: Please post the full stack trace. This should be a chained exception, and perhaps the entire method `MyActivity` with line 283 highlighted

Comment: Did you ever figure out what caused this?

Comment: @McAdam331 - Not yet, it's only happening to one user and I can't replicate it myself.

Comment: @Kon - That is the whole stack trace that I received on the Play Store. Line 283 is the .moveToFirst() call. I'll try and update the question with the code around this later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check the count of the data first, so use this:

```
if(mCursor!=null && mCursor.getCount()>0 ){
    mCursor.moveToFirst();
}
```

Comment: I'll give this a try and see if it stops happening my next release version. I didn't know that moveToFirst() could throw exceptions.

Comment: I'm getting the same error even though getCount() returns 1.  movetofirst() still throws the nullpointerexception. Did you determine the cause?

Answer (score 1):

it's not `mCursor`, but something inside `mCursor` that is `null`. Exactly it is inside `fillWindow` at line `144` according to your `stack trace`.

Usually this kind of NPEs are due to not properly initialized objects. Before you inovke `mCursor.moveFirst()` make sure `mCursor` has sufficient details or data to process your method call.

Comment: Do you mean use getCount() as Gabriella suggests above?

Answer (score 0):

It is important to note from the documentation that [`Cursor.moveToFirst()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#moveToFirst()) will return a boolean value. That boolean represents whether or not the move succeeded.

Instead of checking if the cursor is null, or if it has at least one row, just check the return value of that operation:

```
if(mCursor.moveToFirst()){
   // Do something, we have success!
} else{
   // Ignore, or show toast to let user know something failed, 
   // whatever your business rule is.
}
```

Comment: The problem with this is that calling moveToFirst() is what is causing the crash.

Comment: @Mike Hm, even inside the if statement like that? That's very strange. Is it possible to show what you're doing inside `getCursorData()`? There might be some insight there for us.